# Where can I find the country of origin information of migrants who passed away in the Mediterranean Sea?

Tags: migration, un

I'm planning on making a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0waAysaU_p0) that depicts a map of the locations of the deaths of migrants and refugees that attempt to cross the Mediterranean Sea as time progresses. Specifically, I'd like to show the country of origin of those who passed away. The International Organization for Migration (IOM) has collected [data](https://missingmigrants.iom.int/downloads) on migrant deaths. In their [methodology](https://missingmigrants.iom.int/methodology), it is explained which variables ought to be included in the data sets.

However, some variables appear to be missing. In particular, the “Country of Origin” and “Region of Origin” variables are excluded from the data sets. I've already contacted the IOM about this, but so far they haven't responded to my query.

**Questions**:

1. Have these variables indeed gone missing from the aforementioned data sets, or am I just not looking carefully enough?
2. Is there any way to obtain the country of origin information that belongs to these rows in the tabular data?

Comment: could this be another source? https://data2.unhcr.org/en/situations/mediterranean